# Visual Studio 11 HTML Indentation doesn't work for me

Tags: html, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

I am having trouble making HTML Indentation and auto tag closing work with the default settings for Visual Studio 11 beta.

When I press enter when editing HTML, the next line starts flush to the left without an indent.

What am I missing?

Comment: Isn't VS 11 in beta? I wouldn't expect everything to be working completely correctly in a beta release.

Comment: Is that just on tags or on white space? Could you add a sample of what you're expecting?

Comment: Beta bugs can be reported http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio

Comment: Thanks for tips, yes, VS 11 is in beta, but i were expecting this to work, i will report it as a bug.

Comment: @Alvin Just, when you're writing HTML code in VS 2010 and press enter, the code steps on next line and is indented at the end of previous line, or similarly. This is what I'am expecting.